# Hide interface method in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a such hierarchy:

```
public interface IModule
{
    void Method1();
    void Method2();
}

public interface IPublic
{
    IModule Module { get; }
}
```

In my stuff (feature toggle) i need to hide Method2() for a some time from public interface and make it internal. It will be used in tests, but will be hidden in a release.
is it possible to implement a such thing?

Comment: What sort of tests? Unit tests?

Comment: 2naathon: thanks, but i'm not sure this is relevant to my case.
2Ian: SpecFlow scenarios E2E tests

Answer (score 0):

you could implement it like this probably:

```
public interface IModule
{
    void Method1();      
}

public interface IModule2 : IModule
{
    void Method2();      
}

public interface IPublic
{
    IModule Module { get; }
}
```

then make the actual implementation of IPublic return a IModule2 implementation rather than an IModule then in your feature toggle code cast the IModule to an IModule2. You would also need to check in the Method2 implementation that your toggle is enabled.

This doesn't remove it from the public interface, but makes it not very discoverable. You can't remove it completely though as its always there so the feature can be toggled.

Not great, but a consequence of your feature toggle requirements I think.

Comment: in this case i need to create huge infrastucture for testing. E2E tests work with IPublic

Comment: then you can't hide it I don't think. If your tests test via the public interface then your method has to be in the public interface and will then be public. you can only throw if users try to use this method and shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the code design options, you could use [conditional compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj714084(v=vs.105).aspx) to include or omit `Method2` from the interface, implementation, or both. For example:

```
public interface IModule {
    void Method1();
#if NOT_IN_PRODUCTION
    void Method2();
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another trick to do my magic

```
public interface IPublicInterface
{
    void PublicMethod();
}

internal static class Extension
{
    public static void InternalMethod(this IPublicInterface interface);
}
```

This is not interface, but this is enough by behavior. Before release this method will be moved to interface.